# Sort order in MySQL with 0, null, regular numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have values as follows:

```
ID  
0  
NULL  
NULL  
2  
0  
3
```

Trying to get query sort order so it displays like this:

```
2  
3  
0  
0  
NULL  
NULL
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `IF` statement to enforce your logic and then have the nulls at the bottom. Place a minus sign (-) before the column name to sort nulls.

**Test case:**

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (a int);

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (5);
```

**Result**

```
SELECT *, IF (a = 0 OR a = NULL, NULL, a) as sort_order
FROM mytable
ORDER BY -sort_order DESC
+------+
| a    |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
|    0 |
|    0 |
|    0 |
| NULL |
| NULL |
| NULL |
+------+
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58b399/14